# Failed to use vscode remote ssh, but use ssh directly can work

Tags: ssh, vscode-remote

##### Problem

I re-installed my server system.Before then, I can use remote-ssh normally.However, I can't use remote-ssh to connect to my server anymore.But I can still use ssh directly to connect to the server.
I suppose it managed to get into the system but somehow it broke down.
The error log is below:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-77-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Tue 14 Sep 2021 09:56:58 PM CST

  System load:  0.07              Processes:             117
  Usage of /:   6.5% of 59.00GB   Users logged in:       1
  Memory usage: 10%               IPv4 address for eth0: 10.0.12.2
  Swap usage:   0%

 * Super-optimized for small spaces - read how we shrank the memory
   footprint of MicroK8s to make it the smallest full K8s around.

   https://ubuntu.com/blog/microk8s-memory-optimisation

ready: 6425958cce28
Linux 5.4.0-77-generic #86-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 17 02:35:03 UTC 2021
6425958cce28: running
bash: line 1: _exitcode: command not found
bash: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
bash: line 2: ` elif [[ $ALLOW_CLIENT_DOWNLOAD == "1" ]]; then'
-sh: 4: function: not found
-sh: 69: [[: not found
-sh: 90: [[: not found
-sh: 155: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "then")
Transferred: sent 17180, received 4016 bytes, in 0.5 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 35433.6, received 8283.0
local-server-1> ssh child died, shutting down

[21:56:58.587] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[21:56:58.588] Resolver error: Error: 
    at Function.Create (/Users/luther/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.7/out/extension.js:1:64659)
    at Object.t.handleInstallOutput (/Users/luther/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.7/out/extension.js:1:63302)
    at Object.e [as tryInstallWithLocalServer] (/Users/luther/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.7/out/extension.js:1:387573)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async /Users/luther/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.7/out/extension.js:1:294473
    at async Object.t.withShowDetailsEvent (/Users/luther/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.7/out/extension.js:1:406463)
    at async /Users/luther/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.7/out/extension.js:1:386112
    at async E (/Users/luther/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.7/out/extension.js:1:382710)
    at async Object.t.resolveWithLocalServer (/Users/luther/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.7/out/extension.js:1:385728)
    at async Object.t.resolve (/Users/luther/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.7/out/extension.js:1:295870)
    at async /Users/luther/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.7/out/extension.js:127:110656
[21:56:58.592] ------
```

##### Tried

I tried delete the know_hosts file from host, re-install the remote-ssh plugin, but can't work

I am pretty new to remote-ssh, hope can give me more detailed solution.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

I downgraded remote-ssh.Then I changed my default shell into zsh and upgrade remote-ssh.It began to install '.vscode-server' file again and magically it worked.

Comment: I just spent 2 hours trying to debug a similar issue... racking my brain because I've been working with remote-ssh with no issue for months. Including having just used it the day before. Once I read your comment I finally clued in to check, there was a version update, and downgrading to the previous version fixed my issue.

Comment: Same as @ahfx. I selected "Switch to pre-release version" instead, and it also worked. (as https://stackoverflow.com/a/77079392/7351594)

Answer (score 3):

So it's related to the remote-ssh extension in Visual Code. In my case, I need to switch to the pre-release or previous version to make it work again.

Updated: see screenshots below about how to switch versions. The version **0.106.1** works for me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add the specific versions you had for clarity? Also a quick description of how to switch would be useful.